# Why would a split legal profession explain why 'the rules of court in many [such] jurisdictions are cast as regulations rather than as statutes'?

Tags: civil-procedure

Source: [*Civil Litigation*](https://www.irwinlaw.com/titles/civil-litigation) (Feb. 2010). pp. 29 Bottom - 30 Top.

> In Canada, lawyers are officially both barristers and solicitors but, 
>   as a practical matter, most will work primarily as one or the other. So-licitors, whose work rarely takes them into court, need to understand 
>   the law of procedure as a backdrop to their area of specialization much 
>   as they do the other basic areas of law in which they do not specialize, 
>   but barristers who practice in the area of civil litigation come to know
>
> court procedures and rules through and through. In jurisdictions with 
>   a divided bar, such as England and Wales or Australia, the judges are 
>   traditionally drawn from the ranks of the practising barristers. They, 
>   too, have a keen interest in the law of procedure and a considerable 
>   knowledge of the rules and precedents. **This may help to explain why 
>   the rules of court in many jurisdictions are cast as regulations rather 
>   than as statutes. [Bold mine]** They are a finely tuned set of interrelated rights and 
>   obligations between the parties to the dispute and, sometimes, other 
>   affected persons, and the collateral effect of changes to the rules, which 
>   may be obscure to persons who do not regularly work in a courtroom 
>   setting, is likely to be obvious to those who do.

I understand the distinction between solicitors and barristers under jurisdictions with split legal professions, but still don't clinch how this explains the bolded sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the people who work in courts are better placed to decide what the rules of the court should be than people who work in parliament.

Comment: How does it signify this? The quotation never refers to parliament, only solicitors vs. barristers?